# How to put mono to the current context in reactor

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I got a mono<*> from reactive repository, I want put its value to the context, but I did not found a correct api.

kotlin code:

```
val user:Mono<User> = userRepository.findById(userId)
```

How do I put its value to the reactor context, like this:

```
userRepository.findById(userId).doOnNext {
    // got current context...
    context["USER"] = it
}
```

Comment: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context

Comment: @Toerktumlare Thanks ! I read this doc, but all example in the doc show me to write a block data to context, but I got a Mono object, how do I write to context.
 `xxx.contextWrite(ctx -> ctx.put(key, "Reactor"))`
the value "Reactor" is not a Mono object

Comment: we need a bit more context of what it is you want to do. Why do you want to place the user in the context. You are fetching the user from the database, but why are you fetching it, and were do you want to send the user. I believe that what it is you want to do is not supposed to be solved with the context.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I just do like webmvc, I extract `Token` from `HttpHeaders` in `WebFilter`, and  get userId by decode token, so I fetch User entity from database, then I want put it to context , so I can easily get User in my Controller ? like use `ThreadLocal` in webmvc mode, so I should not use `Context` for doing that? or there is any better way ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Context` represents some metadata attached *at the bottom of the chain*, **at subscription time**. Each individual subscription to a `Mono` can have a different `Context`, and it is more meant to have downstream subscription communicate metadata to upstream operators, not the reverse.

I would greatly encourage you to pursue transmitting the value downstream as a first-class citizen `onNext` (for example, using `map`, `flatMap`, as a `Tuple2`...) rather than attempting to do that by abusing the `Context`.

Comment: Simon Baslé.  thanks~. So what's the right way to hold my `user` when using `webflux` like webmvc, I mean I put user in Filter,  then I can easily get request user in my controller.

Comment: that should be possible in that case, since the filter chain is IIRC "downstream" of your controller. you're not trying to set something at that point but to read something. the recommended way would be to wrap the repository call in `Mono.deferContextual`, which will give you access to a `ContextView` from which you can read values put by the filter chain